# How do inserts into mysql views?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

i have 2 tables

**table.employees**

```
        id, first_name, last_name, post
```

**table.time**

```
        employee_id, work_time
```

**VIEW**

```
        id, first_name, last_name, work_time
```

how i can write one insert for **VIEW** !!?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with MySQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert data into a MySQL view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825941/is-it-possible-to-insert-data-into-a-mysql-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's not (always) possible to determine which values would need to be inserted. For example, your view doesn´t have the `post` column, which might be required, which would make it impossible to insert through a view.

As such, VIEWS are for viewing content only; insertions have to be made on the actual database tables.